# Unable to get service rate limiting to work with systemd 237

Tags: systemd, services

I have read the systemd man pages and also some Q&A here related to `StartLimit*`

I tried what is recommended for newer versions:

```
[Unit]
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=90

[Service]
RestartSec=5
Restart=always
```

Also, what is supposed to work for older versions of `systemd`:

```
[Service]
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=90
...
RestartSec=5
Restart=always
```

(this is still accepted and `systemd-analyze` does not show any errors)

But neither of this works! i.e. my daemon keeps indefinitely restarting
I can see `NRestarts` also showing the correct count.

I am on version `systemd 237` on Ubuntu `18.04` (Bionic). I don't mind using either
format, but I want to make sure that the restart attempt is capped to 5 or 6 times
and no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the configuration you shared works.  You probably need to share more details about the service.

Here are the test steps I ran.  I used Ubuntu 18.04 (`systemd 237-3ubuntu10.53`).

Create a basic shell script to run as a service.

```
cat <<EOF > /usr/local/bin/myservice.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 1
exit 0
EOF
```

Create a basic service.

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/my.service
[Unit]
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitIntervalSec=90

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/myservice.sh
RestartSec=5
Restart=always
EOF
```

Start the service.

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start my.service
```

The logs indicate the service was started 5 times and then went into a failed state.

```
systemd[1]: Started my.service.
systemd[1]: my.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: my.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
systemd[1]: Stopped my.service.
systemd[1]: Started my.service.
systemd[1]: my.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: my.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
systemd[1]: Stopped my.service.
systemd[1]: Started my.service.
systemd[1]: my.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: my.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
systemd[1]: Stopped my.service.
systemd[1]: Started my.service.
systemd[1]: my.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: my.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
systemd[1]: Stopped my.service.
systemd[1]: Started my.service.
systemd[1]: my.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: my.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
systemd[1]: Stopped my.service.
systemd[1]: my.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
systemd[1]: my.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start my.service.
```

Comment: Thanks, the service does not go to failed state in my case! Its a regular unix daemon which does take up some _time to initialize_. Do I have to check/calculate the time my daemon takes to initialize ? Is there some systemd command/logs to show that? (I also have a lot of `ExecStartPre=` and `ExecStartPost=` scripts, if that matters)

Comment: This example did work! I tried to replace sleep with a random value from shell, still it does work!

Comment: BTW, in my case, the daemon is aborting - so, the status will be  `Failed with result 'core-dump'`. But `Restart=always` should cover it! It just keeps going on and on, with: ` -Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
- Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at N.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
`

Comment: "Do I have to check/calculate the time my daemon takes to initialize?"  The service would have to restart 5 times in 90 seconds with these settings to get the "start-limit-hit".

Comment: ok, I will try with some calculations... Is there any `systemd` util/command that can help me here ? (other than seeing the `jouurnal` logs and calculating the time)

Comment: I am not aware of any commands to help calculate the timing.  The journal should be fairly clear though.  It can help to use some filters (e.g. `journalctl -u my.service --since '1 hour ago'`)